# Deployed .NET Core 6 Blazor Server App stops processing HTTP requests after user (in his browser) cleans the cache, and impacts all other clients

Tags: azure-devops, blazor, blazor-server-side, azure-appservice

I have a very bizarre problem.

When one user located in Austria refreshes the cache and tries to reconnect to the Website the application is not processing anymore the HTTP requests, even though the app opens, but the logos that should be fetched from the URL are not coming through neither other HTTP requests. On my end, in the other country in EU it works very good until that user is doing the refresh cache. I have confirmed the replication by communicating with the user that is refreshing the cache, he is using an IOS iPhone device.

I have deployed the Blazor Server in Azure app service, western EU region. I have tried in Linux and Windows plan, and the same issue persists.

Logs are not showing any failure of WebSocket disconnection as Blazor Server is using SingalR. There is not single error that I can trace in the Logs that I have enabled in the application with DEBUG level.

I have tried many configuration of the Hub connection. Here it is the current config in the server part:

```
 services.AddServerSideBlazor()
            .AddHubOptions(options =>
            {
               
                options.HandshakeTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
                options.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
                options.ClientTimeoutInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(40);
                options.EnableDetailedErrors= true;

            })
            .AddCircuitOptions(options =>
            {
                options.DetailedErrors = true;
            });
```

Also at client side I have this part configured:

```
 public static HubConnection TryInitialize(this HubConnection hubConnection, NavigationManager navigationManager)
    {
        if (hubConnection == null)
        {
            hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                              .WithUrl(navigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri(ApplicationConstants.SignalR.HubUrl))
                              .Build();

            hubConnection.HandshakeTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
            hubConnection.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
            hubConnection.ServerTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(40);
        }

        return hubConnection;
    }
```

The problem is that once it is occurred in one user end, then the app is kind of like stopped processing the HTTP for all other users. The page loads well, so I do not think that it is crashing or anything, as no error is logged in any of the following traces:

```
"Logging": {
"LogLevel": {
  "Default": "Debug",
  "Microsoft": "Debug",
  "Hangfire": "Debug",
  "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Debug",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpLogging.HttpLoggingMiddleware": "Debug",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR": "Debug"
}
```

I cannot replicate this in my local machine in any way. Also just in case here is the _Layout page with no specific configuration:

```
<body>
<div id="app">
@RenderBody()

<div id="blazor-error-ui">
    <environment include="Staging,Production">
        An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
    </environment>
    <environment include="Development">
        An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
    </environment>
    <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
    <a class="dismiss"></a>
</div>
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js" autostart="false"></script>
<script>
    Blazor.start();
</script>
<script src="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.js?v=5.0.5"></script>
<script src="js/scroll.js"></script>
<script src="js/sounds.js"></script>
<script src="js/file.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

**The main question is, if any experienced person, who deployed Blazor Server apps had this issue, or where should I be looking to resolve this issue?**

Comment: Is it possible to disable the cache to that specific user just to find out if that temporary solve the issue Just to make localizing the error easier

Comment: Not sure how to disable the cache on IPhone, but for the first time he accesses the page is fine, the main issue is once he cleans the cache the app stops processing and then impacting the whole app for all clients.

Comment: my thoughts were to isolate the issue to ensure finding the core of the problem. Resetting a client cache should affect other clients. There must be something terribly wrong somewhere. do you have other services you register, if so please share the code for service registration.

Comment: Can you please share you program.cs file

Comment: Thanks guys for trying to help. By isolation the problem I was able to find and fix the issue. I am going to add explanation on my question by updating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to isolate the issue, by adding some extra log on the disposing method. It was specific scenario:

1. When users were using the browser, and closed the tab, or cleaned the cache or closed the browser; there was no issue, the disposed method was called and connection was closed.
2. When mobile users closed the tab, or cleaned the cache, disposing method was not called and connection stayed open for 3 minutes, and the biggest problem was that no HTTP request was processed within this 3 minutes until connection closed. And it was affecting all clients, regardless the country location. So the webapp became unusable for 3 minutes.

So I solved this by adding some configuration after services.AddServerSideBlazor().AddHubOptions:

```
.AddCircuitOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.DetailedErrors = true;
                    options.DisconnectedCircuitRetentionPeriod = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
                    options.DisconnectedCircuitMaxRetained = 0;
                });
```

As I do not retain any disconnected circuit, the problem is solved and the webapp is working great.

I came to the solution by understanding that disposed is not called always, I understood from this post: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/39370
and it was explained that:

> Our notification mechanism is a best effort not a guaranteed outcome, since the browser doesn't guarantee that the event is fired. Even in that case, this is a "performance" optimization to eagerly terminate the circuit when we know it won't be used any longer.
> In this scenario dispose gets called after around 3 minutes (by default) when we detect the connection has been lost and the client doesn't re-connect as part of disposing the entire circuit.